# VMware Fusion: Error Loading Operating System after upgrade

Tags: windows-xp, mac, vmware-fusion

I upgraded a Mac from Snow Leopard to Yosemite, but I forgot to shutdown a VMware Fusion VM on it beforehand. The VM was only in sleep mode. The OS of the VM is Windows XP SP3. Now the problem is that after upgrading, the old version of VMware Fusion (3.x) was not compatible with Yosemite. So I upgraded Fusion, and I was able to load the VM and wake it up. I thought everything was fine. However, as soon as I rebooted the VM, I got the error message "Error Loading Operating System".

Comment: I trust you backed up your VM prior to upgrading Fusion.  Assuming you did so, find a Mac with an older operating system, install Fusion 3.x and then properly shutdown your VM prior to opening it within the newer Fusion.

Comment: Yes, I have a backup, thanks to Time Machine. :-)
Well finding an older Mac is not that easy. The easiest is probably to install an older version of OSX on an external drive, and install VMware Fusion 3. I would have hoped for a less time consuming solution. I don't mind fiddling with the vmdk file if necessary.

Comment: P.S. Or if there was a trick to run VMware Fusion 3 on Yosemite... I remember that either Parallels or VMware Fusion would not work on a newer OSX version, but there was a setting one could change in a a config file (a plist file maybe) to trick the software and make it possible to start it on the new OS. Maybe it would not run perfectly but if I could just run the VM to shut it down, it would be enough.